# Looking For a Coordinate Free Way to Prove This Linear Algebra 'Fact'

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, linear-transformations

$$\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}$$
Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$.
(We use $\mc L(V)$ to denote $End(V)$).

For each $v\in V$, define $\Theta_v:\mc L(V)\to V$ as $\Theta_v(T)=Tv$ for all $T\in \mc L(V)$.

> Then each linear functional on $\mc L(V)$ can be written as a composition $\varepsilon \circ \Theta_v$, for some $\varepsilon\in V^*$ and $v\in V$.

If we choose a basis for we and transform the problem in terms of matrices, then the above fact is clear: Operating an $n\times n$ matrix on $(0, \ldots, 0, 1, 0\ldots, 0)^T$, where $1$ is atthe $i$-th position, gives us the $i$-th column of the matrix. Now the $j$-th projection function yields the $i,j$-th entry of the matrix.

**I am wondering how to do this without using bases.**

A natural idea is to define a function $f:V^*\times V\to \mc L(V)^*$ as
$$f(\varepsilon, v)=\varepsilon\circ \Theta_v$$
We note that $f$ is bilinear.
Thus $f$ factors through the tensor product $V^*\otimes V$.

But this doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Can somebody help?

**Edit:**

*I apologize for posting a wrong question. This has been made clear to me by the user whose answer I have accepted. Thanks to him/her.*

Comment: Is $\mathcal L(V)=\operatorname{End}(V)$?

Comment: Yes. I thought this is standard. Let me specify int he question.

Comment: How would you write the trace in the form above?

Comment: I don't follow your comment regarding 'trace'. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: The trace is a linear functional on the space of square matrices, but cannot be written in the form $A \mapsto u^T A v$ for any $u,v$.

Comment: Now everybody is disproving it left right and center! Nice!

Comment: There is no need to apologise. This is the way it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you say is true.

$\mathcal{L}(V) = \text{Hom}(V, V) = V \otimes V^*$.  Your map $\Theta_v: V \otimes V^* \rightarrow V$ is given by tensoring the evaluation map $ev_v: V^* \rightarrow k$ with $V$.

A functional on $\text{Hom}(V, V)$ is the same as an element of $\text{Hom}(V, V)$, the relationship being taking the dual of an endomorphism of $V$.  I find it easier to work here.  Here, $ev_v$ is identified with the map $1 \mapsto v$.  Then, what you ask is that every endomorphism of $V$ is given by $T(x) = f(x) v$ for a functional $f$.  But this isn't true.  What is true is that every $T$ can be written as a sum of such things.

Comment: Thank you. And apologies for the wrong question.

Comment: No need to apologize :)

Answer (score 4):

A different reason why it can't be true is that there just aren't enough $(\varepsilon,v)$ pairs to represent all the functionals when $F$ is finite.

Suppose for example $F=\mathbb F_p$ and $n=3$.

$\mathcal L(V)$ is a 9-dimensional vector space and therefore there are $p^9$ different linear functionals on $\mathcal L(V)$.

On the other hand there are only $p^3$ vectors in $V$ and $p^3$ vectors in $V^*$, so you can't express more than at most $p^3p^3=p^6$ different functionals in the form $\varepsilon \circ \Theta_v$.

Comment: Nice! $\phantom{xxxxxx}$